# Correct use of token based rememberMeService with custom AuthenticationHandler in Spring security

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I have the following config :

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
        <security:remember-me services-alias="rememberMyCompamy" key="MY-KEY" user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="loginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <!-- Adds a logout filter to Spring Security filter chain -->
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="restLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    </security:http>
    <!-- Configures the authentication entry point that returns HTTP status code 401 -->
    <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="uk.co.axiomtechsolutions.ipf.security.authentication.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <!-- Configures a custom login filter bean -->
    <bean id="loginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="restAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMyCompany"/> <!--doesn't do anything?-->
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login"/>
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
        <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true"/>
        <property name="postOnly" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

With this code in my AuthenticationSuccesHandler, which works. I tried a few combinations and this was the only wy to get the cookie created, taken from the excellent tutorials [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-security/) . However programmitically calling rememberMeservice but doesn't *feel* right

```
@Resource(name = "rememberMyCompany")
private RememberMeServices rememberMyCompany;
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
        @Override public String getParameter(String name) {
            return "true";
        }
    };
    rememberMyCompnay.loginSuccess(wrapper, response, authentication);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}
```

A token based rememberMeService is created, along with a service-alias, but I can not set up the login filter to use it unless I do the above, which doesn't feel very springy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticatonFilter` will call the `RememberMeServices` for you, [before your authentication success handler executes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L331). Whether it does anything or not depends on whether [the request contains the "remember me" parameter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L257).

So I'm guessing you don't have that parameter in the request. It's not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to achieve - whether you realise this and want to enable remember-me for all requests or not. To always set the cookie for authenticated requests, you can set the `alwaysRemember` flag on the `RememberMeServices`. However, this isn't exposed through the namespace, so you'd have to obtain a reference to the bean and do it that way (e.g. through a post-processor), or declare the bean manually.

Comment: I was not including the remember me parameter in the request, is ijust literally "remember-me=true" ?

Comment: The default parameter name is [`_spring_security_remember_me`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L44).

Comment: for spring security 4, the default parameter is remember-me